# How can I iterate through JComboBox and Validate items

Tags: java, eclipse, jcombobox

i am trying to iterate through JComboBox items i.e its connected to Database, whenever I click it it fetches data from Database and updates it. But its adding duplicate values in such case. I am trying to validate it by iterating through each item once added to JComboBox, if the existing item is similar to item I am trying to add then it shall not add and jump to other statement.

However I am then getting Null pointer error, in order to avoid this error first time I added `counter -1`, but once items are added and  want to update, it gives error.

My JComboBox code is given below:

```
comboBox.addMouseListener(
            new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
                    List<Guest> list = null;
                    list = database.readGuest();
                    int n = list.size();

                    if(n <= 0) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No data found.");
                    }else {
                        for(int count = 0; count < n; count++) {
                            g = list.get(count);
                            String pass = g.getPassportNp();
                            //String s = (String) comboBox.getItemAt(count-1);
                            //for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                                if(comboBox.getItemCount() != 0) {
                                    if(comboBox.getItemAt(count-1).equals(pass)) {
                                        continue;
                                    }else {
                                        comboBox.addItem(pass);
                                    }
                                }else {
                                    comboBox.addItem(pass);
                                }
                            //}

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

any solution for this?

Comment: How about using a Set as an intermediate or ensure the database doesn't return duplicates?

Answer (score 1):

You are not iterating over the items in the combobox, but only comparing to the last item in it. Your basic design should be 2 nested for-loops, one for going over your database items and one for going over the combobox items to check if the current database item is already in there. (You may also use [List.contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object) instead of an nested loop which is clearer and shorter).

Side note: registering a mouselistener on the combobox seems like a design smell for this type of work. Fetching items from a database is not something you want to do on the EDT, but rather in a background thread. Also, you don't know what happens first: opening/animating the combobox (done by Swing), or modifying its contents? It makes it hard to think about the control flow, yet another reason to take a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which I figured it out. I hope helps others.

I created a List, and then added all items to it then..

```
int size = pass.size();
if(comboBox.getItemCount() != 0) {

    comboBox.removeAllItems();
    for(int c = 0; c < size; ++c) {
        comboBox.addItem(pass.get(c));
        }
}else {
     for(int c = 0; c < size; ++c) {
         comboBox.addItem(pass.get(c));
     }
 }
```